# Invalid Hook call in React in function call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm quite new to react and get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

Situation:
in de index.js file I have the

```
ReactDOM.rend(,document.getElementByID('root'))
```

In this file, before the document.getElementByID, I route to all the different pages using react-router-dom. One of those pages contains a form, when this form is submitted I want to do something with the results of that form.

The form has an onSubmit to a function like:

```
const functionName = () => {
    if (formID === "XXXXXX") {
        <ComponentName/>
    }
}
```

In this function I want to check if the ID of the form matches a certain ID, before calling another Component. Until this point it works perfectly, the function is called, it checks if the ID's are matching, but then:

What is the right way to call another component?

If I use `componentName()` I get this Invalid Hook call because the componentName file has some useState hooks. and if I use `<componentName/>` nothing happens the console logs wont show up in the console etc.

Note: In the componentName file, I just want to get the information that is used in the form, before passing it on to another file. so the componentName file doesnt have to render anything.

UPDATE: To load the forms in a page, there is a button: `<Button fid={id} pageName='pageName'/>`
In that Button file I can use hooks without a problem, the button has an onClick like: `<button className={pageName} onClick={openTF}>buttonName</button>` then that openTF function leads to another page where the form is shown and handled in a popup:

```
const openTF = () => {
        Form(props.fid);
    }
```

From that file on, I can't use any hooks

Update2:
I found out that the  only works in the return part of a Component.
So i rewrote most of the code, and only problem I now have is that in that the return part is rendered everytime the useStates are updated. is there a way to make another  AFTER all the useState. the way it is now the return part is called 4 times, and I only need it one time after all the UseStates

Does anyone know what I do wrong?

Comment: Can you add the logic you have in functionName and what you are trying to do

Comment: There is not a lot of logic there, for the forms on the page, TypeForm is used. but I only have to do stuff in case of one specific typeform. so the only thing I do in the function is to check if the form has the ID of that specific TypeForm, if yes, I need to call the other file, of not, dont do anything

Comment: what do you mean call another component? pls show us how do you call another component

Comment: ```const functionName= () => {
        if (formID === "XXXXXXXX"){
            <ComponentName/>
        }     
    }```

Comment: That is the problem, you can't use component this way. tell us what do you want to do if formId === "XXX"?

Comment: If formID === "XXX" I want to call another .js file and in that file I want to do stuff with the data of the form

Comment: I see. have you add react-router to your project? if you have, you may want to consider jump to another page which contain you <ComponentName/> and continue your work with the form data.

Comment: Can you explain that? I have react-router-dom in my project. My problem is, the only way it seems to go to another page is by using ComponentName() instead of <ComponentName/> and with the </> way nothing happens and with the () way I get this error